# Why don't I see Stack Overflow ad banners in Chrome?

Tags: support

I never knew that SO displayed ads until today. A few minutes ago I opened the Stack Overflow website in IE7 and was surprised to see an ad banner on top of a question. I've been using Chrome for over a year and never needed to move back to IE.

In Chrome, I don't have any extensions like AdBlocker or something installed on my system, so why haven't I ever seen ad banners on top of questions before? Do the developers themselves detect the browser and shows ad accordingly or what? What's the story behind this?

Comment: Maybe you're logged in with Chrome, but not Internet Explorer? You've earned the [reduced ads privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads) on SO.

Comment: ohh k....thanks mate.....thats a great thing done by this team....ya i wasnt logged in on IE :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you've always been logged in in Chrome, and, since you have [over 200 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570928/pankaj-upadhyay) on Stack Overflow, you are shown [reduced advertisements](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads).

In IE7, you would have seen all of the additional advertisements that visitors who are not logged in or have very low reputation see.

Comment: ohh k....thanks mate.....thats a great thing done by this team....ya i wasnt logged in on IE :P